# Azure Mobile Apps vs Mobile Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Azure Mobile Apps vs Mobile Service

I understand there are 2 options when working with mobile apps on Azure.

There is Mobile Services and App service.

Can you explain what are the difference and the architecture of each one ?

Thanks

Comment: I stumbled on this post while asking myself this same question, and figured I'd post links to the documentation that helped me here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/appservice-mobileapps/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mobile Services is now folded in as Mobile Apps in App Service. You should start using Mobile Apps instead of Mobile Services

Comment: I am confused with the offerings. At this point in time "Mobile App" is a thing, but "Mobile Service" is in preview. Doesn't that mean it is being worked on?  If it is deprecated, shouldn't it say so?  Or is there something new coming along that has the same name as something old?

Comment: My understanding is that 'Mobile Apps' is the new offering and the way forward. 'Mobile Services' is still around but was in preview and never made it out. Microsoft suggests going with 'Mobile Apps' for new projects and has migration instructions from Services to Apps. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/

Comment: Mobile Services made it past Preview (RTM). But its now superseded by Mobile Apps.

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Android.  What replaces Mobile Services on the client side?

Comment: As above, use the Mobile Apps client SDK

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Apps is the new version of Mobile Services. But beware, most of the documentation you will find at this present date is for the older version. Some of the features like the Node.js backend is very poorly documented for Mobile Apps.